# Form validation in codeigniter always return false

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new in `codeigniter` and I can't figure out why my `form_validation` keeps on returning false. Here are my codes:

**Login Controller**

```
class Login extends CI_Controller {

     function __construct()
     {
       parent::__construct();
       $this->load->helper(array('form','url'));
       $this->load->library('form_validation');
       $this->load->library('session');
       $this->load->model('user','',TRUE);
     }

     function index()
     {
        $this->load->view('login_view');
     }

     function user_registration_show(){

        $this->load->view('registration_view');

     }

     function user_login_process(){


     }

     function user_registration_process(){

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('fname', 'First Name', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('lname', 'Last Name', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('gender', 'Gender', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('address', 'Address', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('emailadd', 'Email Address', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password1', 'Re-type Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            $this->load->view('registration_view');
        } else {

            $pass = $this->input->post('password');
            $pass1 = $this->input->post('password1');
            if($pass!=$pass1){

                $data['message_display'] = 'Password mismatched!';
            }else{
                $data = array(
                'Fname' => $this->input->post('Fname'),
                'Lname' => $this->input->post('Lname'),
                'Gender' => $this->input->post('Gender'),
                'Address' => $this->input->post('Address'),
                'EmailAdd' => $this->input->post('EmailAdd'),
                'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
                'password' => $this->input->post('password')
                );
            }

        }
     }
}
```

**registration_view**

```
<?php echo form_open('login/user_registration_process'); ?>
<div class="content-box-wrapper">
        <div class="form-group">
             <div class="input-group">
                   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" >
              </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
             <div class="input-group">
                   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" >
              </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
             <div class="input-group">
                  <select class="form-control" name="gender" >
                        <option disabled="disabled">Gender</option>
                        <option value="Male">Male</option>
                        <option value="Female">Female</option>
                   </select>
              </div>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
              <div class="input-group">
                   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address" placeholder="Address">
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
               <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="emailadd" placeholder="Email Address" >
                </div>
           </div>
           <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username" >          
                 </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                 <div class="input-group">
                      <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" >
                  </div>
             </div>
             <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="input-group">
                       <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password1" placeholder="Re-type Password" >
                  </div>
              </div>
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-blue-alt btn-block" value="Register"/>        
</div>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

I am using codeigniter 3.1.3. Can anyone help me?

Comment: where are other required fields like gender address etc on HTML form?

Comment: oh I didn't paste it sir but I have it in my original code

Comment: check form field name should be match from 'set_rules('name')'.

Comment: I already checked it sir but nothing happens, it always return false. I already include the other codes in html form

Comment: @pryxen try removing xss_clean from validation or load helper security

Comment: reference: https://arjunphp.com/php-codeigniter-server-side-form-validation-example/

Comment: @GauravRai you are correct. When I remove the xss_clean the form successfully validated. I tried submitting the form without data but the `required` validation never fired

Comment: @pryxen to use xss_clean you must load security helper google it and you'll ind the solution.

Comment: What are the error messages if any

Comment: It is all working now. Thank you so much @GauravRai :)

Comment: Great, then answer your question with solution and accept it, so others may get some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of sir @GauravRai and advice of sir @Hek-mat this is now my code.

**Login controller**

```
function __construct()
     {
       parent::__construct();
       $this->load->helper(array('url','form'));
       $this->load->library('form_validation');
       $this->load->library('session');
       $this->load->helper('security');
       $this->load->model('user');
     }

     function index()
     {
        $this->load->view('login_view');
     }

     function user_registration_show(){

        $this->load->view('registration_view');

     }

    function user_registration_process(){

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('fname', 'First Name', 'required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('lname', 'Last Name', 'required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('gender', 'Gender', 'required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('address', 'Address', 'required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('emailadd', 'Email Address', 'required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password1', 'Re-type Password', 'required|xss_clean|matches[password]');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            $this->load->view('registration_view');
        } else {


                $data = array(
                'Fname' => $this->input->post('fname'),
                'Lname' => $this->input->post('lname'),
                'Gender' => $this->input->post('gender'),
                'Address' => $this->input->post('address'),
                'EmailAdd' => $this->input->post('emailadd'),
                'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
                'password' => MD5($this->input->post('password'))
              );

            $result = $this->user->registration_insert($data);

            if($result){

                $data['message_display'] = 'Registered Successfully! Please Login to your account.';
                $this->load->view('login_view', $data);
            }else{

                $data['message_display'] = 'Username already exist!';
                $this->load->view('registration_view', $data);
            }

        }
     }
```

I added the `$this->load->helper('security');` in order for the `xss_clean` to validate my form. I also added the `matches[password]` validation to match my `password` field and `Re-type Password` field. Thank you to all of you for helping me solving this problem :)

Answer (score 4):

Your form validation fails due to use of xss clean check in all the fields. If you remove that it validate your fields.As your data is already xss cleaned(assuming global_xss_filtering is TRUE in config)

Comment: This thread discusses this very issue - https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-1192.html

Answer (score 0):

I think there is not matching in field names at getting values using `$this->input->post()`.So try like this..

```
$data = array(
                'Fname' => $this->input->post('fname'),
                'Lname' => $this->input->post('lname'),
                'Gender' => $this->input->post('gender'),
                'Address' => $this->input->post('address'),
                'EmailAdd' => $this->input->post('emailadd'),
                'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
                'password' => $this->input->post('password')
              );
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply sir but that line of code never executed in the first place because the `form_validation` returns false

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html take references from here.

Comment: rather than matching password using if condition use `required|matches[password]` for `password1` field.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion @Hek-mat I will do it :)

Comment: also set your rules in array format because they are clear to see and modify.Hope you can do it.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your all errors in controller. This will return cause of error.

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
```

OR

```
 echo "<pre>";

    print_r($this->form_validation->get_all_errors());

    echo "</pre>";
```

This will return all form error in controller and you can easily handle your request.